# Call Refresh event of grid Polymorphically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, polymorphism

I have a main window in WPF and it contains:

1. A Tab Control having different tabs. Each tab has a different control in it and contains a data grid.
2. A frame control - it also has different controls respectively for data entry.
3. A Refresh Button (Yet to implement)

I have implemented the tab controls and frame for data entry successfully but problem is I cannot refresh the tab control until I switch across the tabs. I want to have a central Refresh button on main-window (one I aforementioned). 
Can anyone guide me how can I do it?

And since tab's current object type will only be decided at the Run-time, so is it Polymorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interface for all the usercontrols:

```
public interface IRefreshAble
{
    void Refresh();
}

public interface ICanDeleteItem
{
    void Delete(/*parameters omitted*/);
    bool CanDelete { get; }

}

public interface IHoldATypedItem ///sorry for bad name
{
    Type TheType { get; }
}
```

Then you implement this interface by the usercontrols:

```
public class TheUserControl : UserControl, IRefreshAble, ICanDeleteItem, IHoldATypedItem 
{
     public void Refresh()
     {
         //Your refreshcode
     }

     public bool CanDelete {get { /*code that indicates if an item can be deleted*/ } }


     public void Delete(/*parameters ommited*/)
     {
          if(CanDelete)
          {
             //Delete Item
          }
     }

     public Type TheType { get { return typeOf(Employee); } }
     // otherstuff
}
```

Now you can put all of your UserControls(for example) in a List<IRefreshAble> and do stuff like:

```
foreach(IRefreshAble item in theList)
{
    item.Refresh();
}
```

If you have more than this Refresh() method common for all Usercontrols you can just expand the interface for this members and get the polymorphism you need.

Comment: Very good approach really. But what if we have to do a functionality for only a certain control. Like Update() or Delete() methods?

Comment: you can have as many interfaces as you need on the UserControl ... perhaps an interface ICanDeleteAnItem. you can check whether a control implements an interface with "control is ICanDeleteAnItem" just as you can to find base classes

Comment: I would use commandbindings and use this checks in the CanExecute eventhandler.

Comment: Sorry if I couldn't convey it properly. I have several controls (UserControl) and all of them need to have Update(), Delete() and Update() methods. While we can use Update() on the whole list without any issue, Delete() and Update() need to know their caller object's type in polymorphic way (correct me if wrong) to be called by exact UserControl

Comment: you can also make an interface with a Type property if you need that... or expand an interface with that property

Comment: I have implemented it using the Abstract class. Now the thing which is stalling my work is how to cast the tab to the class object. Can you please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28977705/casting-a-tabitem-to-usercontrol-in-wpf

Comment: you mean an abstract class deriving from UserControl?

Comment: Yes I have made an abstract class deriving from UserControl as:  public abstract class WorkSpaceViewControl : UserControl
 { //class body }