# Casting a TabItem to UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, casting, tabs, user-controls

I have a Tab Control on my main screen. It has different tab items. For example:

```
<TabControl Name="mainTab"  Padding="0" Margin="70,80,350,49">
            <!--Left,Top,Right, Bottom-->
            <TabItem GotFocus="TabItem_Animals_GotFocus">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    Animals
                </TabItem.Header>
                <ContentControl Margin="10">
                    <Frame Name="animalFrame" Source="AnimalWorkSpaceView.xaml"></Frame>
                </ContentControl>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem GotFocus="TabItem_Calfs_GotFocus">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    Calfs
                </TabItem.Header>
                <ContentControl Margin="10">
                    <Frame Name="calfFrame" Source="CalfWorkSpaceView.xaml"></Frame>
                </ContentControl>
            </TabItem>
```

*and so on..*

Here is design-time preview of tabs:

[image: Tab Controls overview]

Every tab item control is inherited from *WorkSpaceViewControl* (an abstract class derived from *UserControl*)

As you can see there is a *Refresh* button to refresh the control (Reload it's *datagrid* members)

The code behind *Refresh* button is:

```
private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        //var x = mainTab.SelectedItem as TabItem;
        //MessageBox.Show(x.Header.ToString());//shows the header
        //var t = x.Content as TextBlock;
        //MessageBox.Show(t.Text);

        var ctrl = mainTab.SelectedItem as TabItem;

        var myCtrl1 = (WorkSpaceViewControl)ctrl;
        myCtrl1.Refresh();
}
```

Refresh() is a virtual method in *WorkSpaceViewControl* class and overridden in subsequent classes.

Whenever I call that code, it gives me error on casting. I have tried a lot of methods of casting: Implicit, explicit (*as you can see some tries in commented code above as well*).

Here is code of Explicit casting I tried to implement (but failed):

```
public static explicit operator WorkSpaceViewControl(TabItem v)
        {
            if (v.Content is WorkSpaceViewControl)
            {
                return v.Content as WorkSpaceViewControl;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException();
            }
        }
```

It always throws me Invalid Cast by taking into else condition:

[image: Invalid Cast]

Can I cast it and How? Thanks for answering it.

**UPDATE**

The abstract class is:

```
public abstract class WorkSpaceViewControl : UserControl
{
    public WorkSpaceViewControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        //
    }

    #region Inheritance Methods (for sub classes
    public virtual void GetSelectedEntry()
    {

    }

    public virtual void Refresh()
    {

    }

    public static explicit operator WorkSpaceViewControl(TabItem v)
    {
        if (v.Content is WorkSpaceViewControl)
        {
            return v.Content as WorkSpaceViewControl;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        }
    }



    #endregion
}
```

Comment: To be honest I'd rather use UserControls implementing a common interface to achieve your goal like in the previous question... i dont know how to get a control from a frame ... googled some but could not find any... in any case it would be messy... a common interface extracted from your abstract class and implemented by the UserControls currently deriving from this class and you are there... if theres common behavior i'd recommend the approach composition > inheritance...

Comment: I posted a solution with multiple interfaces but you can also make only one with all common members... cast the control to the interface and access it's members and you are there...

Comment: If you'd post the abstract class we can work out a solution

Comment: Actually I want to get it done polymorphically (I dont know the tab type on run time), so Inheritance is must after all.

Comment: You get that polymorphism with interfaces too... I'll show you

Comment: @FlorianSchmidinger Thank you!! Looking forward for it but problem is still.. How to Cast?

Comment: All clear now? Not sure what void GetSelectedEntry() is supposed to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an interface:

```
interface IWorkSpaceViewControl
{
    void GetSelectedEntry();
    void Refresh();

    bool CanSave { get; }
    void Save();
}
```

And a userControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication9.DemoUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnChangeCanSave" Click="btnChangeCanSave_Click">Change CanSave</Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class DemoUserControl : UserControl, IWorkSpaceViewControl
{
    private bool canSave;

    public DemoUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void GetSelectedEntry()
    {
        // Your implementation
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        // Your Implementation
        Debug.WriteLine("DemoUserControl Refresh() executed");
    }


    public bool CanSave
    {
        get { return canSave; }
    }

    private void btnChangeCanSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        canSave = !canSave;
    }


    public void Save()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DemoUserControl Save() executed");
    }
}
```

and a MainWindow:

```
<Window xmlns:WpfApplication9="clr-namespace:WpfApplication9"  x:Class="WpfApplication9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Save" CanExecute="SaveCommand_CanExecute" Executed="SaveCommand_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Name="btnRefresh" Click="btnRefresh_Click">Refresh</Button>
            <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.Save">Save</Button>
        </WrapPanel>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl" Grid.Row="1">
            <TabItem>
                <TabItem.Header>Animals</TabItem.Header>
                <WpfApplication9:DemoUserControl Margin="10" />
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

with Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IWorkSpaceViewControl control = tabControl.SelectedContent as IWorkSpaceViewControl;
        control.Refresh();
    }

    private void SaveCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            e.CanExecute = ((IWorkSpaceViewControl)tabControl.SelectedContent).CanSave;
        }
    }

    private void SaveCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((IWorkSpaceViewControl)tabControl.SelectedContent).Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it cast it this way? I am going to try it and get back to you

Comment: @TalhaIrfan yeah you could check for null before executing Refresh() but that would mean that the control does not implement the interface and then you cant access the control with the interface. My Example correctly writes the message to the debug output...

Comment: @TalhaIrfan directly use the controls though... no frames

Comment: Yeah use the controls directly ... ill expand the example where you bind a command to the window where the button gets disabled when a certain property is false

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Updated... the buttons bound to the command get disabled once you click the button in this demo control...

Comment: @TalhaIrfan Clearing up now or do you still have problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72762/discussion-between-talha-irfan-and-florian-schmidinger).

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
if (v.GetType().BaseType == typeof(WorkSpaceViewControl))
{
    return v as WorkSpaceViewControl;
}
```